# Has Trump freed hundreds of children per month and broken up trafficking rings?

Tags: united-states, politics, donald-trump

Roseanne Barr just tweeted [this](https://twitter.com/therealroseanne/status/979890451200258048) to explain her support for President Trump:

> President Trump has freed so many children held in bondage to pimps all over this world. Hundreds each month. He has broken up trafficking rings in high places everywhere. notice that. I disagree on some things, but give him benefit of doubt-4 now.

My question is, is it true that President Trump has freed hundreds of children per month, and has broken up trafficking rings?

Comment: This is not an answer - just an explainer for people bewildered by the claim: [Daily Beast on Barr's tweets and QAnon](https://www.thedailybeast.com/roseanne-keeps-promoting-qanon-the-pro-trump-conspiracy-theory-that-makes-pizzagate-look-tame)

Comment: Related: [Has Trump's administration been making more human trafficking arrests than the Obama administration?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40084/has-trumps-administration-been-making-more-human-trafficking-arrests-than-the-o) (Barr retweeted this false image right after the tweet from the OP, so she might be referring to false information similar to that). The quoted claim by Barr seems rather vague though and might not be the best fit for skeptics; It seems to be rhetorical hyperbole instead of a factual claim.

Comment: Personally: _No_.